# How I should compare an Date input with an field timestamp in Angular Fire

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

My Question is how I should make a query by compare an input date with an field timestamp in firestore:

- **timeKey** is a:     Timestamp field
- **date** is a:       Sat Oct 05 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Chile Summer Time)

This fields these fields do not match

I will appreciate your help

Thanks

```
this.firestore.collection(DELIVERIES, ref => ref.where('timeKey', '==', date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your document timestamp and JavaScript date object refer to the exact same moment in time, down to nanosecond precision, this query will not give you what you want.  JavaScript object don't even have nanosecond precision, so it's entirely possible that this document could never be found using a query with a Date.

If you want to find a document with a timestamp that occurs within an entire day, you could instead use a range query to specify the start and end time using dates to cover that range (or any other range), for example:

```
this.firestore.collection(DELIVERIES, ref => ref
    .where('timeKey', '>', startDate)
    .where('timeKey', '<', endDate)
```

Comment: Thank's very much  Doug, I get it